# How to write a PostgreSQL query that shows a breakdown based on a TimeStamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have an invitations table with the following fields:

```
Invitations: id, created_at, completed_at
```

I am working to write a PostgreSQL query that breaks down the data by weekly cohorts and shows a breakdown of the completion time by within 1 day of created_at, between 1-2 days and 3 or more days later. Completion time is based on the field `completed_at`

**Desired Output:**

```
weeks_ago | start | end | Total | % Completed in Day 1 | % Completed in D2 | % Completed 3 or days later
0 | 2020-02-04 | 2020-02-11 | ?% | ?% | ?% 
1 | 2020-01-28 | 2020-02-03 | ?% | ?% | ?%
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
SELECT  TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - i.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
                date(min(i.created_at)) AS "start",
                date(max(i.created_at)) AS "end",
                count(DISTINCT i.id) AS "total",
FROM invitations i
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago ASC;
```

**Given my query above, how can I add the following?**

- % of Invitations completed within 1 day of the created_at field
- % of Invitations completed within 1-2 days of the created_at field
- % of Invitations completed 3 or more days later

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . this seems like conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('week', i.created_at) as week_start,
       date_trunc('week', i.created_at) + interval '6 day' as week_end,       
       floor( (date_trunc('week', current_date) - date_trunc('week', i.created_at) / 7) as weeks ago,
       avg( (i.completed_at <= i.created_at + interval '1 day')::int ) as percent_1,
       avg( (i.completed_at <= i.created_at + interval '2 day' and i.created_at > i.created_at + interval '1 day' >)::int ) as percent_2,
       avg( (i.completed_at > i.created_at + interval '2 day')::int ) as percent_3plus
from invitations i
group by week_start, week_end, weeks_ago
order by weeks_ago asc;
```

Comment: this is incredible. couple things for future folks i.started_at should be i.created_at

Comment: fyi, the percent_2 is not working, I think it could be related to `day >):` which is erroring, is something missing after the `day >`?

Comment: also for percent_2, is this right `and i.started_at > i.start_at ` ?

Comment: Does this look right for percent_2? `avg( (i.completed_at <= i.created_at + interval '2 day' and i.completed_at > i.created_at + interval '1 day')::int ) as percent_2,`

Comment: @AnApprentice . . . The single quote was in the wrong place.

Comment: turns out there is an issue w the query. Currently, the query is including invitations that were completed, meaning the denominator is wrong and should include all invitations completed or not completed. Is there a way to update your suggestion to make that work? Thanks